# How to check a string for repeated negative signs? for example --1

Tags: c++, c++11, filtering

I made a function that tells me if I only have digits.

I tried doing `-- ;` however this just messes up my negative numbers.

```
bool isDigit (const std::string &str) {
  return !(str.find_first_of("!@#$^&*()_=+abcdefghifklmnopqrst"
          "uvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ") == std::string::npos);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. please add the code where you are using this function.

Comment: `find_first_of` can't find 2 consecutive elements. Try [<regex>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/regex) header.

Comment: Is there a length limit on `str`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`strtol`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) to read numeric strings and determine if they're valid:

```
bool readNumber(const std::string& input, long& result) {
    char* end;
    result = strtol(input.c_str(), &end, 0);
    return *end == 0;
}
```

This returns `true` if `input` is an integer string, and it saves the integral value in `result`. If you only need to check that the string is an integer, you can ignore the result of `strtol`.

The function will always return `true` for valid integral strings, but `result` will be clamped to the minimum/maximum of `long` if it is outside that range.

Comment: This will fail if the input string is a long number. See my comment.

Comment: `strtol` returns 0 on failure. I'd recommend `std::basic_string::to_string` instead, which throws an exception.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, you probably mean `std::stol`, which is [specified](http://eel.is/c++draft/string.conversions) to use `strtol`. It boils down to stylistic preference whether you want exceptions or not. I believe that my use is safe, as it returns success only if the entire C string was parsed.

Comment: @zneak Yes, sorry for the confusion, I meant `std::stol`. But still, if I can pass string "0" as input, I have to check `errno` to see if I was actually successful or not. Maybe it's stylistic convention, but IMO it's better to use C++ conventions when writing C++ code.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, you can check that `*end` is a NUL character, which I'm doing, to verify that `strtol` parsed the entire string. `strtol` sets `end` to the first character that does not parse.

Comment: @zneak I have no idea why do you insist on using legacy C solutions, but I see now that it's a valid solution.

Comment: Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::size_t nextNonDigit (const std::string &str, std::size_t pos) {
  return str.find_first_of(
      "!@#$^&*()_=+abcdefghifklmnopqrst"
      "uvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
      "-",
      pos
  );
}

bool isDigit(const std::string& str) {
  std::size_t number_minuses = 0;
  for(auto next = nextNonDigit(str, 0); next != std::string::npos;next = nextNonDigit(str, next+1)) {
    if (str[next] == '-') {
      ++number_minuses;
      if (number_minuses > 1)
        return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

if you want to support `,`s or `.`s or limit it to one `.` or 3 between `,`s or whatever you'd have to extend it.  Also, this permits `001-333` as a number.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You gave something to think about.